Flutter Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory despite correct configuration
Flutter Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory despite correct configuration

I'm facing an issue while running my Flutter project where I keep encountering the error: "JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1. Cannot execute C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1\bin\java to determine the version."
I have Java 17 installed at C:\Java\java-17, and I've set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to this path. I've also added C:\Java\java-17\bin to the PATH. Running java -version returns Java 17.0.12, and where java points to the correct path C:\Java\java-17\bin\java.exe.
In my gradle.properties, I set org.gradle.java.home to C:/Java/java-17, and in local.properties, the SDK path is correctly set to C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk. I’ve cleared Flutter and Gradle caches by running flutter clean, deleting the .gradle folder in my user directory, and removing Flutter’s local cache folder. Despite restarting my system multiple times, the error persists.
Running flutter doctor -v still shows that the Java binary is being referenced as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-1\bin\java, and it cannot execute that path to determine the version. This seems like Flutter is still picking up an old or cached configuration.
How can I resolve this issue and ensure Flutter recognizes the correct Java path?

looks like the 7 is missing in your path:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17 \bin\java

Yeah, but I have added that to the actual path in the environment variable and don't have a clue why it is accessing the path with one character left.
